# Chrome extension storage remove not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension and I'm having a problem with chrome.storage.sync.remove

Let's say this is the content from my chrome.storage :

[image: my chrome storage]

And this contains the items I want to remove (removedItems[])

[image: removedItems[]]

This is my code :

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(data) {
    coasterList = data;
    console.log('FFFFFFFF :',coasterList.data);
    chrome.storage.sync.remove(removedItems[0].CoasterName, function(data) {
      chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(data) {
        var coasterListFINAL = data;
        console.log('FINAL LIST :',coasterListFINAL.data);
        //console.log(removedItems[0].CoasterName);
      });
    });
  });
```

Nothing is happening when I do :

```
chrome.storage.sync.remove(removedItems[0].CoasterName, function(data) {...}
```

What am I doing wrong ?
(I have no errors but the key I want to remove, is still here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOUR CODE:

```
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'CoasterList':coasterListClean}, function() {
        console.log("SAVED");
    });

/*
if you try to retrieve the newly set storage var "CoasterList" right after setting it this way
you will probably get the old value 'cause you are reading something that is not changed yet
ALL CHROME.STORAGE APIS ARE ASYNCHRONOUS!!!
*/
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(data) {
        console.log(data.coasterList);
    });

----------------------------------
/*
if you want to retrieve the new value of CoasterList you have
to get it inside the storage.sync.set callback function.
if you are under MV3 rules you can also use the "promise returned" syntax
THIS SHOUL WORK
*/
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'CoasterList':coasterListClean}, function() {
        console.log("SAVED");
        chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(data) {
            console.log(data.coasterList);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Seems to work but I'm trying to rewrite the part where my user adds item to this list.
But Thank you !

Comment: YEAH GOT IT WORKING ! 
I did rewrite the other part where my user creates his list, now it's working fine ! 
Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete a single array items stored in chrome.storage. You have to replace the whole array with a new array where you have previously remove that item.

Comment: How would I do that then ? 
With a chrome.storage.sync.set() ?
So I create a new array without the items I want removed and then chrome.storage.sync.set() ?
I'm fairly new with chrome extension

Comment: Yes, with chrome.storage.sync.set. You remove first the array item (e.g with array.splice method) then you put that array in storage with chrome.storage.sync.set. There cannot be more than an object with same name in chrome.storage, so that "set" command overwrites the old value with the new one.

Comment: The problem with array.splice is that you need the specific index to replace something, which I don't have cause the array depends on the user, he can add item to this list.

Comment: Then you can use others array methods like "find" or "findIndex". See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp for details.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still didn't manage to get it working.
I did 
chrome.storage.sync.set(coasterListClean, function(data) {
    console.log("SAVED");
  });

(where coasterListClean is my array with the removed elements and I get :
Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of storage.set(object items, optional function callback): No matching signature.

Comment: chrome.storage.sync.set({key: value}, function() {
  console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
});

Comment: Back at beginning, no errors but won't get updated.
The value I deleted is still there,even when I call a new 
chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(data) {
    var coasterListFINAL = data;
    console.log('New list:',coasterListFINAL.data);

  });

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LAbwShCB I wrote it there, it's easier to read
Edit : 
I saw something,I did that in my get:
console.log('New list:',coasterListFINAL.data);
but when I do only console.log('New list:',coasterListFINAL);
It shows a new list but inside my previous 
Here a screenshot : 
https://imgur.com/a/qOCLX6n

Comment: I think I have a problem when creating the list,and updating it, thank you very much for your help ;) I think I understood better now.